# Siunitx comma as separator in unit exponent

Tags: siunitx, french

I'm writing a report in French in which I want to display units with non-integer exponents:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \sisetup{locale=FR}
    Value of \SI{39.2}{\mega\pascal\metre\tothe{0.5}}.
\end{document}
```

In French commas are used as decimal separators. It works fine for the value of 39.2, but the comma does not follow in the exponent.

[image]

The same happens with the macro `\raiseto`. Any ideas how to get this right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's currently an oversight here in the code. For the present, use

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__siunitx_unit_format_power_aux: {
  \str_if_eq:VnTF \l__siunitx_per_mode_tl { repeat }
    { \__siunitx_unit_format_power_repeat: }
    { \__siunitx_unit_format_power_per: }
  \str_if_eq:VnF \l__siunitx_tmpa_tl { 1 }
    {
      \__siunitx_unit_format_power_brackets:
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l__siunitx_unit_current_tl
        {
          \exp_not:N \PrintSuperscript
            {
              \__siunitx_unit_format_power_aux:n
                { \exp_after:wN \__siunitx_unit_format_power:w \l__siunitx_tmpa_tl . . \q_stop }
            }
        }
    }
}
\cs_new:Npn \__siunitx_unit_format_power:w  #1 . #2 . #3 \q_stop
  {
    \exp_not:n {#1}
    \tl_if_blank:nF {#2}
      {
        \exp_not:V \l__siunitx_output_decimal_tl
        \exp_not:n {#2}
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
    \sisetup{locale=FR}
    Value of \SI{39.2}{\mega\pascal\metre\tothe{0.5}}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: That does the trick... thanks!